# Expo React native fetch strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-api, fetch, expo

I am currently using React Native with Expo for an application. I made a login using a Google account and I try to take some information about the user using Google's API. I use "fetch" for this, but it doesn't work at all, not even printing an error. I wrote a wrong link for "fetch" and still not even an error thrown. I am running the code on my devices remotely using Expo. Here is the code:

```
async  logIn() {
  try {
    const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
      androidClientId: '645999128246-gv9drk3gtad84ikeifg37p4k5phdu705.apps.googleusercontent.com',
     // iosClientId: '116235701426-lsptd400ahlctrlveoe4vlg96hcjne51.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
    });

    if (result.type === 'success') {
      //console.log("AICI");
      getUserInfo(result.accessToken);
      return result.accessToken;
    } else {
      return {cancelled: true};
    }
  } catch(e) {
    return {error: true};
  }
}
 async getUserInfo(accessToken) {
  try {
  let userInfoResponse = await fetch('https://www.wronglinkdoesntmatter.com/userinfo/v2/me', {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`},
  });
  console.log("IT IS FINE");
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
}
  render() {
  this.logIn();
```

Comment: hi, can you make a snack to make this self-contained and reproducible?